# Preguntas de SF en SO en español

Tags: discusión

¿Se permitirán en SO en Español preguntas que normalmente corresponderían a ServerFault?

La duda me surge a partir de esta pregunta: [¿Cómo puedo integrar esta validación para acceder al OWA de Office 365 o portal.office.com?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483/tengo-office-365-y-uso-adfs-3-0-como-sso-como-puedo-integrar-esta-validaci%C3%B3n-p)

Tal vez no es el mejor ejemplo, pero supongo que se entiende la idea.

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido marcada como duplicada de [Sitio tipo: “ServerFault” o “SuperUser”](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174/sitio-tipo-serverfault-o-superuser) sin ambargo dicha pregunta tiene un sentido diferente, ya que es un propuesta que debería haberse hecho en Area51.

Comment: Relacionado con [Encuesta: definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161), mas específicamente con http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/166/65